# PSQL - Copy from csv file if column item does not exist

Tags: postgresql, csv, psql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to import a csv file into the postgres table where I can successfully do so using **COPY FROM**:

*import.sql*

```
\copy myTable FROM '..\CSV_OUTPUT.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

But that query only adds rows if it is currently not in the database, otherwise it exits with an error. ***Key (id)=(#) already exists.***

**myTable**

```
  id  |    alias    |    address            
------+-------------+---------------
  11  |   red_foo   |   10.1.1.11
  12  |  blue_foo   |   10.1.1.12
```

**CSV_OUTPUT.csv**

```
  id  |    alias    |    address            
------+-------------+---------------
  10  | black_foo   |   10.1.1.11
  12  |  blue_foo   |   10.1.1.12
  13  |  grey_foo   |   10.1.1.13
  14  |  pink_foo   |   10.1.1.14
```

My desired output is to insert the rows from the csv file into postgresql if **address** does not exist. **myTable** should contain grey_foo and pink_foo already but not black_foo since its address already exist.

What should be the right queries to use in order to achieve this? Your suggestions and ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the data into a staging table first, and then update your main table (`myTable`) with only the rows with the keys that don't already exist.  For example, assuming you have imported the data into a table named `staging`:

```
with nw as (
    select s.id, s.alias, s.address
    from staging as s
    left join mytable as m on m.address=s.address
    where m.address is null
    )
insert into mytable
    (id, alias, address)
select id, alias, address
from nw;
```

If you can upgrade to Postgres 9.5, you could instead use an `INSERT` command with the `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` clause.

Comment: is there any way to do this using the copy command only?

Comment: @LostCrotchet - The OP was using PG 9.3, which did not support a WHERE clause in the COPY command.  As of PG 12, a WHERE clause in the COPY command is supported.  Therefore, it is probably possible to do this using the COPY command only with any PG version of 12 or later.  I have not tested this; it sounds like you have a reason to do so.